# Unable to open cloudera manager on GCP

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, cloudera

I am creating a Hadoop cluster with Cloudera as a distribution on the Google cloud platform.

I am installed Cloudera but when I am trying to access Cloudera Manager with my instance_expernal_ip:7180, I am getting This site can’t be reached.

I am able to trace IP.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Have you created a [firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) for port 7180?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether your cloudera manager is first running on the terminal. Use `jps` to see if you actually see your cloudera manager running. If it is not running, you can go to the cloudera directory which is usually inside `/home/cloudera`. Then run the following command.

```
./cloudera-manager --express --force
```

After that you will be able to view the cloudera UI taking the fact that you have actually opened up the port to be publicly accessible.